# Activating Bootstrap 4 tab after $.post event

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I'm having a bit of a curious issue. I had no problem doing this when I was using Bootstrap 3.

I have a page with two tabs. Tab1 is currently active and Tab2 is disabled. Tab2 only becomes enabled when data is entered into Tab1 and is submitted via a Submit button. Tab2 should display dynamically generated content within a .

Note that I had no problem doing this when using Bootstrap 3. However, with Bootstrap 4, what happens is that the data is submitted and Tab2 is displayed, but Tab2 is still showing the content of Tab1. If I click back on Tab1, then back on Tab2, the dynamically generated content is now shown.

The javascript I use for this is (assuming 'ria' is the id for the form and 'ria_result' is the id of the enclosing div within Tab2):

```
            var formData = $('#ria').serialize();

            $.post('ria.php', formData,

             function(data){
                     $('#ria_result').html(data);
                    $('.nav-tabs li:eq(1) a').removeClass('disabled');
         $('.nav-tabs li:eq(0) a').removeClass('active');
         $('.nav-tabs li:eq(1) a').addClass('active');
         $('.nav-tabs li:eq(1) a').tab('show');
                    });
```

The html for the tabs is:

```
<div class="col-12" id="tabs">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="riatab" role="tablist">

 <li class="nav-item"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link active" role="tab">Details</a></li>
 <li class="nav-item"><a href="#tab2"  data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link disabled" role="tab">Results</a></li>
```

```
  <div class="tab-pane show in active" id="tab1" role="tabpanel">
    ....form content.....
  </div>

<div class="tab-pane"  id="tab2" role="tabpanel">
    <div id="ria_result" name="ria_result"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I'm struggling to see what I am missing here. Any suggestions ?

Thanks
Neil

Comment: Can you post the relevant code or create a working snippet?

Comment: The html for the tabs is: